# Trying to set up wireless router, failing

Tags: wireless-networking

I am trying to set up Netgear's wireless-n WNR2000 router, following their oversimplified 5- step process for plugging in wires, and I'm not having any success.

It comes down to: once everything is wired and turned on in the correct order, all of the LEDs match the image they give of 'what should be lit up', but their setup disk still doesn't find the router.

They have a site to set up the router manually, www.routerlogin.net, which I cannot navigate to, even while wired directly to the router.  `http://192.168.1.1` doesn't connect to anything, either.

The interesting part: i get ping replies from Google's DNS server at 8.8.8.8 while this is set up.  but cannot connect to any web site by name, since the router's DNS isn't set up.

One thought is that the router and modem both have the same IP address, so it's conflicting, but I'm not sure how I'd resolve that.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `ipconfig /all` and seeing what the IP of the main gateway on your network adapter is, that should make sure you're trying to access the right IP. The fact you're even getting ping replies from `8.8.8.8` should mean there's no IP conflicts, you're getting through to the internet fine enough.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your router (and this will reset the default gateway back to 192.168.1.1). Then reset your modem.  Power down everything and start from scratch.  Reboot your computer as well.

Re-establish network connectivity and the ability to connect to the outside world and the internet.

You may want to turn off all your firewall tools (and maybe AV software too) while troubleshooting this process.

Do you have another computer you can add to the mix for pinging, like a laptop?  This sometimes helps with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I've turned off modem/router several times, rebooted computer, all in various orders, and that never resolved anything.

ipconfig /all shows the connection with default gateway of 192.168.1.1

ipconfig /flushdns did not help

connecting to www.routerlogin.net fails.
interestingly enough, attempting to access http://192.168.1.1 failed with a request refused.
All the while, I can ping DNS servers.

I am ashamed to say that the problem was resolved behind the scenes using the netgear 'connection genie' program or whatever it is called.

The connection is set up fine, but now I have no idea what it did 'behind the scenes' to fix it.  Any speculation?